# Hide shrink button in full screen mode on iOS

Tags: swift, uiwebview

I am playing YouTube videos within my app via a `UIWebView`. I am able to load the videos and play them full screen on the device. I have disabled `allowInlineMediaPlay`, however, when the video goes full screen, there is a shrink button on the media player. When the shrink button is pressed, the video goes out of full screen mode and shrinks back to its original size but continues playing, I want the video to stop playing if it shrinks.

Ideally, I'd like to remove the shrink button altogether and just leave the Done button.

Is it possible to remove the shrink button from the media player?

Comment: Did you manage to solve this issue? It's giving me a lot of problems since I'm depending on detecting a `UIWindow` disappear in order to do some work.

Comment: No, couldn't find any way to remove the button.